# Test Rigor to recognize your selection on a pop up action in a browser

Tags: testrigor

I'm creating a automation test using [Test Rigor} in chrome when I start a phone call a pop up will appear to Enable Microphone and Video. However Test Rigor isn't recognizing it. Is there a command that will

Answer (score 0):

testRigor automatically closes all the popups.